# How bypass ISP using CGNAT and open all ports? SSH? VPN?

Tags: router, ssh, port-forwarding, nat, ipv4

First of all sorry for my english.
IPv4 connections are routed through carrier grade NAT(CGNAT) and the ISP does not provide IPV6. This way I can't open any port.
I tried reverse tunneling (ssh) on a specific port using a vps and it worked. So I was able to access the service on the PC from anywhere, just by placing the ip of the vps and the specified port.
However I would like to have all ports released. (example: localhost:1=vps_ip:1...localhost:65535=vps_ip:65535) Only with the exception of the port I'm using for ssh.
If i can't do this through ssh you could tell me what would be the best way to do it and preferably if you could send a tutorial.

Comment: Get a VPN with a static IP address.  (Google VPN static IP - they are common, and typically use OpenVPN).  If you ate not needing third parties to access your systems you could set up a VPN server on your vps, and then a client to your PC. You could set up another client from other remote sides to allow them to access your PC on its VPN interface, but this won't allow the wider internet to connect as it won't have a real ip

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ssh` to tunnel a complete "virtual" network interface on your VPS, see e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525262/193028).

You can then port forward all ports you need to this tunnel interface on your VPS.

You won't be able to do this with *all* ports, because you still need ports to communicate with the VPS (e.g. 22 for `ssh`).

---

> OK, but there would be no configuration to release "all ports", so I don't need to configure for each server that will be opened.

Not sure what you mean by this. You need `iptables` rule to port forward every single port you are interested in from the external network interface in your VPS to the tunnel interface. So you **do** need to configure this for each port (or conversely, add an exclusion list). Google something like "port forwarding iptables" for more information.

> I found vpn`s called openvpn, softether, wireguard ...

You are using `ssh` as a sort of VPN, because that's what you were asking about in the question. You can use a different kind of VPN, if you want.

Comment: OK, but there would be no configuration to release "all ports", so I don't need to configure for each server that will be opened.
Regarding vpn I found a post saying that I could use it to open ports and use it on the PSN that has NAT 3 and "release nat" (I found vpn`s called openvpn, softether, wireguard ...)
Could you tell me if this is correct, as I see that you have an experience in this part of networks and I am just a beginner.

Comment: Wait, even your own VPS, is connected to your network under cgnat. So How is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, however with the recent issues with TMobile Home Internet, bypassing cgnat is a must! This GitHub link will give you options and guides on what and how to use, if someone sees it. Also a Facebook group but I don't use Facebook...so...ya...

https://github.com/mochman/Bypass_CGNAT

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a way to connect directly. You either need a coordinator or need to know the ip address of whoever wants to connect and keep sending udp packets to them continuously so that they can connect on demand.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)
**edit:** Forgot that this is not a networking site and only mediocre answers are welcome. keep the downvotes flowing.

Comment: I didn't vote!!

Comment: You overlooked the "VPS" (virtual private server) in the question. The OP already has a VPS with a public IPv4, and can use ssh with reverse tunneling on a specific port. So there **is** a way to connect directly (his private PC connects to the VPS via ssh), and other parties connect to the VPS, as well. Your answer only applies to the situation where there is no external server you can use (which is not the case for this question). And since there is already a server available, you don't need a "coordinator", you can just tunnel directly through the server.

Comment: @dirkt I didn't overlook the VPS. Nowhere in my answer did i say the VPS can't be the coordinator itself. my answer is the closest to `directly` one can get without shenanigans or having a lower MTU than provided by the network.

Comment: But the use case the OP has is not "use STUN or something similar to directly connect two hosts behind NAT". The use case the OP has is "have a public IPv4 that I can use conveniently, and forward it to my PC behind NAT without public IP". And the OP already has used ssh port forwarding to achieve part of it. Now he wants the rest. You are not getting downvoted because "this is not a networking site, only I understand networking, everyone else here is stupid". You are getting downvoted because you are not addressing the question with its use case, and substitute your own use case instead.

Comment: @dirkt Exactly. With the method I provided one can simply put in `ip=$(custom-hole-punch-command 80); curl $ip`. but what do I know? I got downvotes, I must suck.

Comment: 1) The OP already had halfway finished port forwarding, instead of explaining him how to do the rest, you told him "there isn't a way to connect directly" 2) If you have to introduce an alternative method, at least describe advantages and disadvantages compared to the other method. For example, it may or may not possible for his intended usage to use "custom-hole-punch-command some-browser" 3) At least list possible implementations (STUN etc.), and give him some links on both how to set up a server, the necessary modifications for the client. Do you see now the problems with your answer?

Comment: @behrooz you've decided to morph the question into one about how he can get from his client to the server "directly", when he hasn't mentioned that at all. That's why the downvotes are flowing - you missed the actual question, and instead just left this unhelpful.... thing... here. Your answer does *nothing* to address the OP's specific question about how to configure multiple ports for forwarding on an existing tunnel through a VPS. You say only mediocre answers are welcome..... but what does that make this?

Comment: @schizoid04 It is in fact you who don't understand the question. Other solutions involve tunneling, VPNs, etc. My solution(port punching) involves no modification of daemons, tunneling, TCP over TCP, TCP over UDP, double encryption, etc. because it uses normal TCP connections directly between the nodes.

Comment: @behrooz that's great and yet it doesn't matter because it's *not what he's asking for*. But if we take a moment to assume you're right - It's still a terrible answer. Just short linking to a wikipedia article does nothing that a cursory google search wouldn't do - it does nothing to help him understand how to implement it. In general answers that are just links with little explanation are bad answers, and answers that just say "no" are bad answers, and I think we can at least agree on that, if not the actual question that's being asked here. Hence, downvotes